# RemoteView does not change image

Tags: android, service, remoteview

I have a service that displays a notification when it starts. The notification looks like `MediaPlayer` controls. When the pause button is clicked, the `Service` is called again and the media player pauses. On clicking again, it resumes playing. However, the images do not toggle. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    MediaPlayer player = PodcastrApplication.newInstance().getMediaPlayer();
    request = intent.getIntExtra(REQUEST_CODE, 0);
    if(request == PAUSE){
        // Toggle Play and Pause
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            player.pause();
            rm.setImageViewResource(R.id.pause, R.drawable.ic_action_play);
        }else{
            player.start();
            rm.setImageViewResource(R.id.pause, R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
        }
    }else if(request == DISMISS){
        hideNotification();
        stopSelf();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**Why does it not work?**

I thought it was a thread issue so I even tried using a `Handler` but that did not work either.
Another hack is to cancel the notification and display a new one all together which seems pretty expensive to do.

Comment: I got the same problem with, our code is so similar ^=^,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a little change. I added a new method:

```
 private void updateNotification(){
        NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                  .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        MediaPlayer player = PodcastrApplication.newInstance().getMediaPlayer();
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            rm.setImageViewResource(R.id.pause, R.drawable.ic_action_play);
        }else{
            rm.setImageViewResource(R.id.pause, R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
        }

        Notification notif =  new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContent(rm)
        .build();

        mgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notif);
}
```

Re-issuing the notification with the same ID updates the notification.

Comment: great  solution tnxxx